# Apply a function with target function args in advance and get returned results to be applied on that target function

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq

I've updated this post now with actual scenario that I'm trying to solve. I'm using `Flask` to build RESTful api with `flask-restful` plugin and `pika` library to work with `RabbitMQ`. For example, this snippet of code illustrates a RPC request for authorization using info about user permission and bearer token.

```
    def request_authz(self, metadata):
        """
        For an RPC request, the RCP client sends a message with two
        properties (i.e. `reply_to` and `correlation_id`) set to its
        callback queue
        """
        self.response = None
        self.correlation_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

        props = pika.BasicProperties(reply_to=self.callback_queue,
                                     correlation_id=self.correlation_id)

        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange=AMQP_EXCHANGE,
                                   routing_key=BINDING_STATISTICS,
                                   body=json.loads(s=metadata),
                                   properties=props)

        while self.response is None:
            self.conn_broker.process_data_events()
        return self.response
```

And this snippet of code illustrates a `POST` API endpoint for accessing to resources after authorization is approved while has not been implemented yet. That `metadata` should be params acquired from this `request`.

```
    def post(self):
        items = info(args=request.get_json()['params'])
        return {'data': items}
```

I want to make sure that all api should be authorized via `request_authz`. In other words, all api should get `response` returned by `request_authz` that indicates if it is authorized or not. How to do this in pythonic way (e.g. using **decorator**) ?

Comment: You may use `if value > 0`, or is there any reason you're trying to avoid that? If you need a separate function, shorten the code to `return value > 0`. Another area of simplification is that `func1` and `func2` appear to be doing the same thing, just with different print statements. Something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

You could report the `print`s to a single function:

```py
def util(value):
    if value > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def check_value(value, value_type):
    if util(value):
        print('%s is %s' % (value_type, str(value)))
    else:
        print('%s must be positive' % value_type)

def func1(value):
    check_value(value, 'perimeter')

def func2(value):
    check_value(value, 'area')
```

Moreover, the `util` function can be reduced to:

```py
def util(value):
    return value > 0
```

Comment: Sorry, I've updated this post for actual scenario. But I hope that I express my question this time :).

Answer (score 0):

The util function could be reduced to

```
def util (value):
    return value > 0
```

The return will be the same. In the original you say

```
if value > 0:#If condition is true return True, if not return False
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Its easier to just return the camparation result